# Computer freeze when running this python script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

It's been 3 times that my whole PC freezes (not only my browser) when I run this script (after about 15 seconds). I run it through jupyter notebook.

And here is my configuration :

- Windows 10
- Firefox 99
- CPU i5-4670K 3.4GHz
- 16GB RAM
- SSD

To summurize, I try to scrap some informations from a list of Facebook pages (20 lines in a file).
I am using selenium to scrap the number of likes, the email address and the website from the "about" section. Then I write it in a CSV file.

The task manager does not show ram or cpu saturation.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import re # regular expression
import csv

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""
    
email_regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'

ser = Service("C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\Python\\chromedriver.exe")
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser)

file = open('pages_list.txt', 'r')
page_lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

with open('facebook_pages.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, lineterminator='\n')
    
    for page_url in page_lines:
        page_url = page_url.strip()
        webdriver.get(page_url)
        sleep(2)
        full_content = webdriver.find_element(By.ID, 'facebook')

        # Get the text between "Se connecter" and "Pages connexes"
        # Be aware, depending on the facebook page, it may load different facebook versions !
        metadata = find_between(full_content.text, 'Se connecter', 'Pages connexes')
        nb_likes = 0
        email = ''
        website = ''

        if metadata:
            # Scrap
            for line in metadata.splitlines():
                # Scrap the number of likes.
                if 'personnes aiment ça' in line:
                    line = line.replace('personnes aiment ça', '')
                    nb_likes = int(line.replace(' ', ''))

                # Scrap the email address.
                if(re.fullmatch(email_regex, line)):
                    email = line.strip()

                # Scrap the website
                if ((line.startswith('https://') or line.startswith('www.')) and line.find('instagram') == -1 and line.find('youtube') == -1):
                    website = line.strip()

            if(nb_likes and (email or website)):
                print([page_url, nb_likes, email, website])
                writer.writerow([page_url, nb_likes, email, website])

        print('Page : ' + page_url)

file.close();
webdriver.quit()
print('Finished!')
```

Have you any idea? It would be appreciate!

Comment: How big is your page_list.txt. You use `sleep(2)` between every call, so if it's a big file it can take really long.

Comment: @Damiaan For now, there are only 20 lines. And I set sleep(2) to be sure... I would like to decrease the sleep time. But even with only 20 lines it freezes...

Comment: @MallauryGérard consider test again, but, only with 1 link - value from `page_list.txt`. Also ,"full_content.text" = the content is too large? - it would be helpful if you add the sample data you're scrapping with this code.